# Unable to locate Spring NameSpaceHandler - Spring's mvc-basic in equinox using MANIFEST.MF similar to web-console Spring DM sample webapp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, osgi

Trying to deploy Spring's mvc-basic in Equinox container.

Brief error (full below):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring   NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]
```

mvc-basic's app-config.xml:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.mvc.basic" />
```

web-console's applicationContext.xml:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-osgi/tags/spring-osgi-1.2.1/samples/web-console/war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

changed slightly (i.e., changed spring-context.xsd to spring-context-3.0.xsd) to match mvc-basic's app-config.xml (patch is linked below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

    <!-- OSGi package admin service reference -->   
    <osgi:reference id="packageAdmin" interface="org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin"/>

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="org.springframework.osgi.samples.console.service" />
```

---

Source:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk

OSGi patch:
http://gist.github.com/631236

---

Reference Source:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-osgi/tags/spring-osgi-1.2.1/samples/web-console

Patch to update Spring to 3.0.3.RELEASE and make context schemaLocation *exactly* equal to mvc-basic:
http://gist.github.com/631241

---

Pax Runner bundle file adapted from:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-osgi/tags/spring-osgi-1.2.1/samples/web-console/war/libs/configuration/config.ini
http://gist.github.com/631268

To run:
http://paxrunner.ops4j.org/space/Pax+Runner

```
pax-run --p=equinox http://gist.github.com/raw/631268/cfc79d68a309c5fed75e8030a5e3a74760d697f9/spring-osgi-1.2.1-web-console-and-mvc-basic.bundles
```

Error:

```
Timer-2 INFO [xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]
Timer-2 ERROR [servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4371)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer.startCatalinaContext(TomcatWarDeployer.java:144)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer.startDeployment(TomcatWarDeployer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.support.AbstractWarDeployer.deploy(AbstractWarDeployer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.extender.internal.activator.WarLoaderListener$DeploymentManager$DeployTask.doRun(WarLoaderListener.java:257)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.extender.internal.activator.WarLoaderListener$DeploymentManager$BaseTask.run(WarLoaderListener.java:215)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.timer.DelegatingTimerTask.run(DelegatingTimerTask.java:70)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Timer-2 ERROR [[localhost].[/mvc-basic]] - StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4371)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer.startCatalinaContext(TomcatWarDeployer.java:144)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer.startDeployment(TomcatWarDeployer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.support.AbstractWarDeployer.deploy(AbstractWarDeployer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.extender.internal.activator.WarLoaderListener$DeploymentManager$DeployTask.doRun(WarLoaderListener.java:257)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.extender.internal.activator.WarLoaderListener$DeploymentManager$BaseTask.run(WarLoaderListener.java:215)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.timer.DelegatingTimerTask.run(DelegatingTimerTask.java:70)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Timer-2 ERROR [[localhost].[/mvc-basic]] - Servlet /mvc-basic threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4371)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer.startCatalinaContext(TomcatWarDeployer.java:144)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer.startDeployment(TomcatWarDeployer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.support.AbstractWarDeployer.deploy(AbstractWarDeployer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.extender.internal.activator.WarLoaderListener$DeploymentManager$DeployTask.doRun(WarLoaderListener.java:257)
    at org.springframework.osgi.web.extender.internal.activator.WarLoaderListener$DeploymentManager$BaseTask.run(WarLoaderListener.java:215)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.timer.DelegatingTimerTask.run(DelegatingTimerTask.java:70)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Thank you!

Misha

EDIT: Just tried with Spring DM 2.0.0.M1 which uses Spring 3.0.0.RC1 out of the box.

Relevant .bundles files are:
spring-osgi-2.0.0.M1.bundles
http://gist.github.com/633280

spring-osgi-2.0.0.M1-with-mvc-basic.bundles
http://gist.github.com/633283

2.0.0.M1 reference source:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-osgi/tags/spring-osgi-2.0.0.M1/samples/web-console

Unfortunately, the 2.0.0.M1 org.springframework.osgi.* jars are not available (to my knowledge) in any bundle repositories, so you must first download and compile spring-osgi-2.0.0.M1 from this subversion repo:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-osgi/tags/spring-osgi-2.0.0.M1

Comment: Do you have spring-context-x.y.z.jar in your classpath/webapp?

Comment: Yes, I do: 11 ACTIVE      org.springframework.context_3.0.3.RELEASE. Plus if I didn't, I don't think the web-console example would work as it references the same exact spring context Namespace in its applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext is required. Helpful references:
http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/web.html

Retrieve relevant patch:

```
wget http://gist.github.com/raw/648295/452aaeeceed8fae6b9a4d035a5c2d2ad939f65bf/mvc-basic-osgi-works.patch
```

Command to start mvc-basic using OSGi:

```
svn checkout https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk --quiet && cd trunk && patch -p0 < ../mvc-basic-osgi-works.patch && mvn clean install -DskipTests && bash run.sh
```

This assumes that you have downloaded mvc-basic-osgi-works.patch into the current folder.

Some things still don't seem to work, e.g., ${pageContext...} tags, but other than that seems to work.

Misha